Blazor windows forms error showing problem
part of my Program.cs for loading Form1 that loads webview:
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(null)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true"); // detailed errors
        webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:5000;http://localhost:5000;https://localhost:5001;");
        webBuilder.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");                
    })
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
    {
        configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    })
    .Build();        

host.StartAsync();        
ServiceProvider = host.Services;
var form1 = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Form1>();        
Application.Run(form1);   
host.StopAsync();

with this, when any error occures in Blazor, the error location in .razor file not showing and the form1 is not accessible so that I use F12 console for error descriptions.
The Visual studio stops at line: Application.Run(form1);  and shows me a general error, like null reference exception. How to make error reporting as normal?
